# How to find iOS back button programatically with FlutterDriver

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I'm using [FlutterDriver](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/flutter_driver/FlutterDriver-class.html) to perform integration testing for a [Flutter](https://flutter.io/) package.

When the platform is Android, an [AppBar](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html) is used in the scaffold, and when the platform is iOS, a [CupertinoNavigationBar](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoPageScaffold/navigationBar.html) is used.

When testing on Android I can find the back button with the following code

```
await driver.tap(find.byTooltip('Back'));
```

However this fails on iOS. As the button is generated automatically I'm unable to add a tag programatically. Any suggestions for how to select it on iOS? Bonus points for cross-platform solutions.

Also, any suggestions for simulating an android-device back button tap (outside of the app)?

Comment: Have you ever thought about using the `WillpopScope` widget to capture whenever the back button or back arrow is pressed?

Comment: @Arendhal that's the problem, I can't get FlutterDriver to tap the back button because I can't find the appropriate selector for it.  WillpopScope is not useful in this scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
await driver.tap(find.pageBack());
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please fully explain your answer. While it might be clear to you, one line of code is not a high quality response.

Comment: Honestly, it couldn't be more succinct

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the accepted solution `await driver.tap(find.pageBack())` didn't work for me.

So I added `Key` to the `AppBar` and accessed the `BackButton` like below

```
  final appBar = find.byValueKey("appBarKey");
  await driver.waitFor(appBar);

  final back = find.descendant(
    of: appBar,
    matching: find.byType('BackButton'),
    firstMatchOnly: true,
  );

  await driver.tap(back);
```

Answer (score 1):

i found this

```
 find.byType(CupertinoNavigationBarBackButton);
```

im unaware if this is more or less performant or if it relies on something else to work

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the `find.pageBack()` works fine only for EN locale. For other languages it simply fails to find the widget.

You can get localized `pageBack` like this:

```
SerializableFinder pageBack(String locale) {
  switch (locale) {
    case "es":
      return find.byTooltip("Atrás");
    case "fr":
      return find.byTooltip("Retour");
    case "de":
      return find.byTooltip("Zurück");
    case "it":
      return find.byTooltip("Indietro");
    default:
      return find.pageBack();
  }
}
```

Source: https://medium.com/@eduard.carreras/flutter-driver-find-pageback-not-localized-56ca092fb026

Answer (score -1):

you can use `tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.arrow_back_ios));` to click the back navigation bar on ios devices